# Evaluating an irreducible polynomial in a trascendental element

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $X, X_1, \dots, X_n$ be indetermiantes, $f \in \overline{K}[X_1, \dots, X_{n-2}, X]$ be an irreducible polynomial and $\mu \in \overline{K(X_{n-1},X_n)}$. Is it true that $f(X_1, \dots, X_{n-2}, \mu)$ is still irreducile over the field $\overline{K(X_{n-1},X_n)}$?
I guess that this is true but I can't explain it rigorously.
Can anybody help me?